# Angular UI - tabs inside tabs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui

Newbie question. How to have vertical tabs inside horizontal ones with Angular UI (bootstrap).

I tried to do this as following:
http://plnkr.co/edit/L3sNliwBTcpgWjpFwjOw

No luck as you can see.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this same issue.  It appears to work fine in 0.4.0 of Aungular UI - Bootstrap, but not in 0.5.0 as in your example.

http://plnkr.co/edit/ROMOqn9gPc0IBKgxh8LN

There is also a related issue that's currently open in github (#783).  It appears directly related and produces the same javascript error as your plunker.  I can't post this link because I don't have enough reputation points at the moment to post more than two links.  The other two links were more informative.

In my case, I also ended not using angular UI and just used angular concepts with bootstrap.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Xor7B8erA1b8aD3FhEi2

Hope that helps!